# Error while exiting application with another thread running

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've got a code like this:

```
int main(){
    thread loop2(loop2);

    while(running){

    }
}

void loop2(){
    while(something){

    }
}
```

When `running` turns to `false`, the program should exit. But I'm getting an error from VS: `-abort() has been called.`

I know that this happens because the second thread is still running. I tried to terminate the thread with `~thread()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Nothing in this code sets `running` to false. In fact, your program exhibits UB because your threads don't take ever I/O or terminate on their own.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sets *what* to false? I see no declaration for something called `running`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
while(running){

}
```

by

```
loop2.join()
```

It will wait until the thread is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't just arbitrarily invoke some object's destructor whenever you feel like it!

Instead, you should *interrupt* and then *join* the thread.